# Text next to image, limit text height to image height

Tags: css, image, height

So, I have an image and there should be a teaser-text next to it.

The text should fade out at the bottom and display a ">>" as read further-indicator & link.

Now to the problem: the text-side should only be as high as the image.

Is there any way to limit the text-column's height to the height of the image and place the fadeout & link at the bottom?

```css
.su-post-img
{
  float: left;
    display: block;
    max-width: 67% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}

.su-post-excerpt
{
}

.su-post-title
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: xx-large !important;
}


.fadeout {
    position: relative; 
    bottom: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
    ); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
    );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
    );
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
    );
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="su-post columns">
  <div class="column su-post-img"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/DSBmG1Tl65XysmdiC92sBuA4WQImAqViuKo1zZD9ZGgOpKTnR0hp3EoJW1MlX8JWKLwXdxvZYgcz_HM4WN1uWVKslNkgXeEbtWfP=w234-h160-l80-sg-rj-c0xffffff">
    </div>
            
  <div class="column">
  <section>
    <h2 class="su-post-title">This is the title</h2>
    <div class="su-post-excerpt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. derit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
      nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. derit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
      nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <div class="fadeout"></div>   
    </div>
                
    <a href="www.google.com">>></a>
    </section>
  </div>
        
</div>
```

UPDATE:

With the excellent answer from @Terminator-Barbapapa I solved my problem.

I added some JS to the answer to allow for dynamic image heights.

Here is my full solution:

```js
// Set height of text column in post to height of image.
function AdjustTextHeight()
{
    if (jQuery('.su-post-img').css("flex-basis") != "100%")
    {
        var height= document.getElementById('post-thumb').offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById('post-text').style.maxHeight=height.toString() + "px";  
    }
}                   

// add to events
$(window).resize(function() 
{
    AdjustTextHeight();
});

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    AdjustTextHeight();
});
```

```css
.post
{
  display: flex;
}

.post-img img {
  flex-basis: 35%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-text
{
  flex-basis: 65%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.post-text::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, white 70%);
}

.post-continue {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <div class="post-img">
    <img id="post-thumb" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/DSBmG1Tl65XysmdiC92sBuA4WQImAqViuKo1zZD9ZGgOpKTnR0hp3EoJW1MlX8JWKLwXdxvZYgcz_HM4WN1uWVKslNkgXeEbtWfP=w234-h160-l80-sg-rj-c0xffffff">
  </div>
            
  <div id="post-text" class="post-text" >
  
    <h2>This is the title</h2>
    <div class="post-excerpt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. derit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
      nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. derit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
      nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                

    </div>
    <a class="post-continue" href="www.google.com">>></a>  
        
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex` to place your columns next to each other. And apply a `max-height` based on the height of your image. Also you can easily create the fade-out with a `::before` pseudo element, so you won't need extra HTML markup. Position your link absolute at the bottom of your `section`.

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
}

.column { 
  min-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.su-post-img img {
  height: 200px;
}

.su-post-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

section::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, white 70%);
}

section a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="su-post columns">
  <div class="column su-post-img"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/DSBmG1Tl65XysmdiC92sBuA4WQImAqViuKo1zZD9ZGgOpKTnR0hp3EoJW1MlX8JWKLwXdxvZYgcz_HM4WN1uWVKslNkgXeEbtWfP=w234-h160-l80-sg-rj-c0xffffff">
    </div>
            
  <div class="column">
  <section>
    <h2 class="su-post-title">This is the title</h2>
    <div class="su-post-excerpt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. derit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
      nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. derit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
      nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <div class="fadeout"></div>   
    </div>
                
    <a href="www.google.com">>></a>
    </section>
  </div>
        
</div>
```

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted, and possible vote it up.

Comment: Hi, sorry, it took me a couple of days to get around to working on the problem again. The answer works great, thank you. I added some JS to make it work on arbitrary image heights (e.g. when rezising the window).
Will update my question with my full solution.